# Google Cloud Directory Sync and AD link through LDAP

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, ssl-certificate

I have been working to link my AD to G-Suit and have an auto sync established. The reason I put this here because I have had hard time to figure out everything. I am still not at the end of this procedure and I would appreciate if the skilled people would contribute to help me and I guess many others as well, on this topic.

I downloaded GCDS tool (4.5.7) and installed on a member server. Tried to go through the steps and failed, except to the first one to authenticate to Google.

**Learnt:** It is a Java (Sun) based product and when it come to authentication or SSL it will through errors that need to be sorted.

Step 1, Google Auth - done and very simple as long as you can logon to your GAE account

Step 2, LPAD config... this was tricky

- I created a service account to use

**Learnt:**
You need to have the SAMS account matching with the displayname and name as well; only this way I could authenticate. 
In most cases you don't need any admin rights, a domain user should be able to read the DN structure from LDAP.

- I have the OU structure, but I need LDAP working on the DC (this works somehow)

**Learnt:**
Simple connection through port 389;
SSL would use port 636;
in most cases

- GCDS only uses Simple authentication!

**Learnt:**
With port 389
Domain group policy needed to changed to non LDAP auth required (Domain controller: LDAP server signing requirements changed to none!) to be able to logon - this one is working and good for DEVSERV

*Question: Should I use it for PRODSERV or I need to aim to use SSL?*

**Learnt:**
With port 636 (SSL) you need a certificate

*Question: I tried to add self cert based on the following [article](https://content.spiceworksstatic.com/service.community/p/post_attachments/0000176808/597a8c40/attached_file/Enable_LDAP_over_TLS_on_a_SonicWall_without_a_CA.pdf), added to the trusted cert root but Google cannot see it?*

- BASE DN can be read out through LDP.EXE (built in LDAP browser by MS)

**Learnt:**
You can add your OU you wanted doesn't have to be the root of the tree

*Question: does it mean you have implemented extra security?*

Step 3,Defining what data I can collect. OU and person I picked.

**Learnt**
Profile will collect extra information to Google, such as job title, phone etc. I only wanted them for the company signature... Well that is still not clear if this can be done. If that is not possible, I can't see the reason why I should disclose unwanted information to store on another server.

*Question: Can job description be included to the Google Mail signature?*

I am keep adding my finding to it as I am working through but would appreciate any input from people who managed to set it up.

Step 4, Searching in the Organisation Unit - confusing again but it is done. (More to follow.)